# Still get E/JavaBinder﹕ !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!! Error even image has compressed

Tags: android, bitmap, bitmapimage

I'm trying to return the selected image from **Activity B** to **Activity A** `list View` like image below. But some of the image cannot be returned from **Activity B** to **A**  even I have compressed them, I still get

```
 E/JavaBinder﹕ !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!! Error.
```

**Activity A ListView**

[image]
**Activity B**

```
     Button addImage, submit;
      Bitmap photo,bmp;

    private void activeTakePhoto() {
            Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        }

     @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                        Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            switch (requestCode) {
                case RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE:
                    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK & null != data) {
                        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                        try{
                            photo=MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(),selectedImage);
                            ByteArrayOutputStream stream =new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                            photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                            bytes= stream.toByteArray();
                            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
                            imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
                        }catch(IOException e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    break;

  submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { //return value to Activity A
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
                amount = Amount.getText().toString();
                description = Description.getText().toString();
                type = spinnerType.getSelectedItem().toString();
                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                byte[] bytes = stream.toByteArray();
                returnIntent.putExtra("type", type);
                returnIntent.putExtra("description", description);
                returnIntent.putExtra("amount", amount);
                returnIntent.putExtra("photo", bytes);
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
                finish();

            }
        });
```

**Activity A**

```
 Bitmap ReceiveImage, photo;

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { // receive from Activity B and populate ListView A
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == PROJECT_REQUEST_CODE) {
                ReceiveType = data.getStringExtra("type");
                ReceiveDescription = data.getStringExtra("description");
                ReceiveAmount = data.getStringExtra("amount");
                byte[] bytes = data.getByteArrayExtra("photo");
                Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
                if (mClickedPosition == -1) {  // if icon clicked
                    if (obj != null)
                        obj.addNewItem(ReceiveType, ReceiveAmount, bmp, ReceiveDescription);

                } else {
                    if (obj != null)
                        obj.changeItem(mClickedPosition, ReceiveType, ReceiveAmount, ReceiveImage, ReceiveDescription);
                }

            }
```

**Edited**

**Activity B**

```
  @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                    Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE:
                if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK & null != data) {
                    selectedImage = data.getData();
                    String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver()
                            .query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null,
                                    null);
                    cursor.moveToFirst();
                    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                    String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                    cursor.close();
                    Bitmap a = (BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
                    photo = scaleBitmap(a, 200, 150);
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(photo); // image looked blurry
                }
                break;

            case REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE:


                Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes);
                String fileName = "tempimg.jpg";

                try {
                    photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
    }



  submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { // return value and image to Activity A listView
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
                amount = Amount.getText().toString();
                description = Description.getText().toString();
                type = spinnerType.getSelectedItem().toString();
                returnIntent.putExtra("type", type);
                returnIntent.putExtra("description", description);
                returnIntent.putExtra("amount", amount);
                returnIntent.putExtra("img_uri", selectedImage.toString());
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
                finish();
            }
        });
```

**Activity A**

```
   PicCustomBaseAdapter obj;
    ArrayList<ImageAndText> images = new ArrayList<ImageAndText>();

      @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { // receive from Activity B and populate ListView A
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                if (requestCode == PROJECT_REQUEST_CODE) {
                    ReceiveType = data.getStringExtra("type");
                    ReceiveDescription = data.getStringExtra("description");
                    ReceiveAmount = data.getStringExtra("amount");
                    ReceiveImage = data.getParcelableExtra("photo");
                    Uri imgURI = Uri.parse(data.getStringExtra("img_uri"));
                    // Toast.makeText(getApplication(),ReceiveType+ReceiveAmount+ReceiveDescription+"",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    if (mClickedPosition == -1) {  // if icon clicked
                        if (obj != null)
                            obj.addNewItem(ReceiveType, ReceiveAmount, imgURI, ReceiveDescription);
                    } else {
                        //if (obj != null)
                        //  obj.changeItem(mClickedPosition, ReceiveType, ReceiveAmount, ReceiveImage, ReceiveDescription);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

      btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) { //  button is clicked
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), a + "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                     uploadImageAndText(images, lastID);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomePage.class);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
            });

  public void uploadImageAndText(ArrayList<ImageAndText> listItems, final String id) {
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
            try {
                for (ImageAndText i : listItems) {
                    JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
                    String type = i.getType();
                    String[] Type = type.split(":");
                    object.put("type", Type[1]);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Type[1], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    String amount = i.getAmount();
                    String[] Amount = amount.split(":");
                    object.put("amount", Amount[1]);
                    String description = i.getDescription();
                    String[] Description = description.split(":");
                    object.put("description", Description[1]);
                    Uri uploadImage = i.getImage();
                    imagess = getImage(uploadImage); // cannot resolved getImages
                    object.put("image", imagess);
                    object.put("ts_id", id);
                    jsonArray.put(object);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            AddStaff ru = new AddStaff(jsonArray);
            ru.execute();

        }

        class AddStaff extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
            ProgressDialog loading;

            JSONArray jsonArray;

            AddStaff(JSONArray jsonArray) {
                this.jsonArray = jsonArray;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                loading = ProgressDialog.show(AddClaims.this, "Please Wait", null, true, true);
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();
                data.put("listItems", jsonArray.toString());
                data.put(Configs.KEY_IMAGE,imagess);
                RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();
                String result = rh.sendPostRequest(Configs.STAFF_BENEFIT, data);
                return result;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                loading.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
```

**staffBenefit.php**

```
<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){

        if( !empty( $_POST['listItems'] ) ){

            $mysqli = new mysqli("127.0.0.1:3307", "root", "", "androiddb");
            if( $mysqli->connect_errno ) echo "Failed to connect to MySQL";

            $image = $_POST['image'];

            $listItems = json_decode( $_POST['listItems'], true ); 

            $sql="SELECT id FROM staff_benefit ORDER BY id ASC";

            $id=0;

            $res=$mysqli->query( $sql );
            while( $rs=$res->fetch_object() ) $id=$rs->id;

            $path="$id.png";
            $actualpath="http://192.168.107.115:80/Android/CRUD/PhotoUpload/$path";

            $sql="INSERT INTO `staff_benefit` ( `type`, `amount`, `description`, `image`, `ts_id` ) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ? )";
            $stmt=$mysqli->prepare( $sql );

            $pathelements=array( realpath( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ), 'CRUD', 'PhotoUpload', '' );
            $savepath = realpath( implode( DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $pathelements ) ) . "{$id}.png";

            $bytes=file_put_contents( $savepath, base64_decode( $image ) );
            if( !$bytes ){
                echo 'Error saving image';  
            }

            if ( $stmt ) {
                 foreach( $listItems as $item ){ 

                    $stmt->bind_param('sssss', $item['type'], $item['amount'], $item['description'], $actualpath, $item['ts_id'] );
                    $res=$stmt->execute();

                    if( !$res ) echo 'Query failed with code: '.$stmt->errno;
                } 
            }
            $mysqli->close();
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Parcel](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/os/Parcel.html) used for sending data using `Intent`. as see here:

[TransactionTooLargeException:](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/os/TransactionTooLargeException.html)

> If the arguments or the return value are too large to fit in the
>   transaction buffer, then the call will fail and
>   TransactionTooLargeException will be thrown.
>
> The Binder transaction buffer has a limited fixed size, currently 1Mb...

So if we send `byte` Array of any large image will cause `TransactionTooLargeException`.

For sending image between two application components is use image URI,image path,id,... instead of sending Bitmap or byte Array.

In your case do it as:

**1.** Send `selectedImage` URI which getting in `onActivityResult`  using Intent from Activity B to A:

Change :

```
   returnIntent.putExtra("photo", bytes);
```

to:

```
   returnIntent.putExtra("img_uri", selectedImage.toString());
```

**2.** Get `img_uri` as String in Activity A from Intent then parse it to URI. In `onActivityResult` method of Activity A:

Change :

```
byte[] bytes = data.getByteArrayExtra("photo");
```

to:

```
Uri imgURI = Uri.parse(data.getStringExtra("img_uri"));
```

**3.**  Change `addNewItem` method second parameter to URI from  `Bitmap` and pass `imgURI` :

```
obj.addNewItem(ReceiveType, ReceiveAmount, imgURI, ReceiveDescription);
```

**4.** In ListView Adapter use `setImageURI` for setting image for ImageView:

```
imageView.setImageURI(imgUri);
```

Comment: `Error:(205, 39) error: incompatible types: Uri cannot be converted to URI` and Error:(209, 68) error: incompatible types: URI cannot be converted to Bitmap

Comment: `URI imgURI = Uri.parse(data.getStringExtra("img_uri"));` onActivityResult

Comment: @Tony: mistake, use Uri instead of URI

Comment: @Tony: use `image.setImageURI(imageFromClaims);` where `imageFromClaims ` is uri

Comment: @Tony: From where getting image to show in ImageView?

Comment: I getting the image from camera and gallery sir